# FacesContext and what is ClientId

Tags: jsf, facescontext

Can you explain me why we need in `String clientId` in the method

`void addMessage(String ClientId, FacesMessage msg);`?
Is it true that when client sent an initial request to server then server assign to this client a specific `String ClientId`. As i understand `FacesContext` created when aplication deployed and runnig the first time and this `FacesContext` is unique for application. Is it true?

Comment: In future questions, please ask one question per question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Client id in `FacesContext#addMessage(String clientId, FacesMessage message)` is needed to be able to add a specific message to a specific component. You can either specify a client id of the component you'd like to assign the message to, or `null` to add the message to the messages stack not tied to a specific component. The latter will be updated in e.g. `<h:message for="clientId>`, while the latter in e.g. `<h:messages globalonly="true">`. You can add a message to global messages in case it is not component-specific, for instance, when database operation failed.

Comment: In other words, it's thus very definitely **not** some ID of the enduser (client) who's visiting the website as the OP seemed to think.

Comment: @BalusC The second part of the question is disastrously badly written so I decided not to touch it at all (probably should've linked to some of the opus answers of yours, but that's terrifyingly slow on a cell phone so I hope OP's going to do that on his own). As to your comment, OP could have also probably confused that with `jsessionid` that "identifies a client".